# Is SU (or any other Stack Exchange site) an only English-speaking community?

Tags: support

Passed this question on SU [Comment autoriser toutes les application du windows store ainsi que le windows store a passer le fire-wall](https://superuser.com/q/648593/228536) and this question came to my head.

**Is SU (and SE by extension) only an English-speaking community?**

I'm not asking about the chat (since they were meant to be *lax* in regards to these formalities) but there is no place on the help pages that *explicitly* says this is an English-speaking community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is, unless the specific community explicitly isn't. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) and the [official policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/). Considering help is in English, it should also be implicit.

Comment: Implicit isn't explicit, therefore the question. And it wasn't on any resource **new** users would find at start of their journeys through SE. But thanks for the links.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - The good news is there are more then a few people who are able to read and write mutliple languages and the community often posts answers in the author's native language if we know it.  Although we do expect the question to be in English even if the answer is posted in multiple languages.